# Which action hook can I use when a featured image has been selected

Tags: images, wp-update-post

I have made a plugin for wordpress which copies the image to another directory when a post has been edit. But if you only upload another featured image and don't save the post. The image has been attached to the post, but the post has not been updated. Which does not trigger my plugin function. Show which trigger (action hook) can I use to also copie the featured image?

The action which I now use for the post edit is [wp_insert_post()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post).

I forgot the reason why I use [wp_insert_post()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post), but maybe that's why it fails ;)

Comment: Please show your actual code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `set_post_thumbnail` function uses the metadata functions to set the featured image.

You have two actions to hook into that process:

#### EDIT: The action hooks are now defined different

Thanks @dalbaeb!

- `update_postmeta`, before the data is written into the database. Previously `update_post_meta`
- `updated_postmeta`, after the data is written into the database. Previously `updated_post_meta`

#### SECOND EDIT: No need to panic

`updated_{$meta_type}_meta` and `update_{$meta_type}_meta` still work.

You will have to make a conditional, and be good to go:

```
if ( $metakey == '_thumbnail_id' ) { /*blabla*/ }
```

Comment: I believe now it is `updated_postmeta` ([link](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/updated_postmeta)) and `update_postmeta` ([link](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/update_postmeta))

Comment: Actually upon further inspection there's also `updated_{$meta_type}_meta` ([link](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/updated_%7B$meta_type%7D_meta)) and `update_{$meta_type}_meta` ([link](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/update_%7B$meta_type%7D_meta)) actions, so technically all four will work. Sorry about that!

Comment: `updated_postmeta` doesn't seem to work any longer. After checking the docs, I found `attachment_updated` was added in WP 4.4: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/attachment_updated/