# Featured Image Action Hook

Tags: hooks

Is there a hook available that returns the featured image, once a featured image is set to a post?

I checked [Which action hook can I use when a featured image has been selected](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/76693/which-action-hook-can-i-use-when-a-featured-image-has-been-selected) and the action hooks mentioned does not get executed when the featured image is added.

Comment: the image choice is saved when the post is saved then informations on this other question are still valid.

Comment: @Kaperto Thanks I am able to get the _thumbnail_id if the user saves the post. But user need not to save the post to set the featured image. In this case how do I get the featured image?

Answer (score 2):

If you wanna catch the event before saving the post, you won't be able to do this with PHP - setting the featured image is done with JavaScript (there is a hidden field and it's value is populated with JS when user picks a thumbnail from Media Uploader. Also the thumb preview is rendered with JavaScript.) So WordPress hooks won't be useful here, you need to look for a JavaScript event.

Good news is that you can still work with JS an wp.media API like this:

```
// listen for featured image selection event
wp.media.featuredImage.frame().on( 'select', function(){

    // get the selected image ID
    var thumb_id = wp.media.featuredImage.get();

    // there you go, thumb_id is the picked image ID
    console.log( thumb_id );
});
```

This would get fired every time a user sets a thumbnail from the Uploader.